# wxPython AboutDialog icon not centered

Tags: python, image, wxpython

I have a problem with the `wx.AboutBox`. My image (or icon if you want) is not centered as the one in the tutorial - I'm on Windows 7 and the tutorial is likely to be tested on Ubuntu - is that it?

[image: My aboutdialog:]

[image: The tutorial:]

The code:

```
    about = wx.AboutDialogInfo() 

    about.SetIcon(wx.Icon('Fartberegneren.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG))
    about.SetName('Fart Beregneren')
    about.SetVersion('1.0')
    about.SetDescription(description)
    about.SetCopyright('(C) 2012 - 2013 Casper William Medom Nielsen')
    about.SetWebSite('http://www.casperwmn.dk')
    about.AddDeveloper('Casper William Medom Nielsen')
    about.AddDeveloper('Rasmus Bøje Larsen')
    about.AddDocWriter('Casper William Medom Nielsen')
    about.AddDocWriter('Rasmus Bøje Larsen')

    wx.AboutBox(about)
```

Comment: Layouts *should* be platform independent. Is the tutorial code working for you on Win7?

Comment: What kind of container is `about`? What are the setting, e.g., width, height, layout-direction, ... I think this part of your code is crucial

Comment: @Thorsten, Sorry i have edited in what about is :-) at: phineas, Yes, the code is working fine and showing the box though as the picture shows the icon is placed oddly on the left side instead of the middle.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, but I'm on Ubuntu. What is the version of your wx? Mine is 2.8.12.1. The whole layout of the Dialog seems to be changed (Look at "Developers" and "Documentation writers").

Comment: @Thorsten, My version reads 2.8.12.1 aswell. I noticed that aswell and wondered about it a bit, figured it was something with windows - its fairly odd that it's different, as phineas said it should be platform independent?

Comment: This is really peculiar. Maybe you should carry your question to the [mailing list](http://wxpython.org/maillist.php), probably they see immediately the point.

Answer (score 3):

I got an answer by reporting it:

"It's not a bug, it's an attempt to approximate the native behaviour. There is no well-defined standard for the about box under Windows but the most usual layout puts the icon to the left.
More generally speaking, wxAboutBox doesn't make any guarantees about its appearance under the given platform as it wraps the native dialog if available. If you need something looking in the same way under all platforms you can always (easily) use a generic dialog in your own code."

Answer (score 1):

Not only your code, but even the demo demonstrates the same problem for me on Windows 7 with wxPython 2.8.12.1. Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Thank you! I am glad it is not me that is doing something wrong :-)

Comment: I am just using `wx.richtext` for my About dialogs, so I have never noticed. Weird.

Comment: Tkanks for the hint of a sort of solution!